# A set that can never be approximated by an $F_{\sigma}$ set

Tags: measure-theory

Denote the Lebesgue outer measure by $m^*$. Question: Can we construct a set $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $m^*(E)<\infty$ and $m^*(E) > m^*(F)$ for every $F_{\sigma}$ set $F \supset E$?

The motivation is the following: it is easy to prove that for every $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ we can find a $G_{\delta}$ set $V$ such that $V$ contains $E$ and $m^*(E)=m^*(V)$. It is, however, hard to show that for every $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ we can find a $F_{\sigma}$ set $F$ such that $F$ contains $E$ and $m^*(E)=m^*(F)$ (I can only show it with the additional assumptions that $m^*(E)<\infty$ and $E$ is measurable). It makes me wonder whether the second result is true or not.

To answer the question, we need a set which is not Lesbesgue measurable and has positive outer measure. I was trying the complement of some Vitali type set but it does not seem like I am going anywhere.

Comment: I don't have time to think about this now, but maybe something in my 5 February sci.math post [Remarks on Bernstein sets](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/GCl-79BcPXM/m/sxp7dgz9zTYJ) (one correction [here](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/GCl-79BcPXM/m/QaaZ0eMcoGQJ)) will help.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I will read it and see if I can come up with anything.

Answer (score 1):

It can be shown that a subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ of finite outer measure is measurable if and only if there exists a set $K\subset A$ of $F_{\sigma }$ type such that $m^* (A) =m^* (K).$

Comment: Yeah I know that. But here I am talking about the outer measure and $E$ is not supposed to be measurable.

Comment: @温泽海: Note the statement in the answer is "if and only if". So if $A$ is has finite outer measure and $A$ is NOT measurable, then there does NOT exist a set $K \subset A$ of $F_{\sigma}$ type such that  $m^*(A) = m^*(K).$ Thus, if $A$ has finite outer measure and $A$ is not measurable, then for every set $K \subset A$ of $F_{\sigma}$ type we have $m^*(A) \neq m^*(K).$ However, by monotonicity of outer measure, we can strengthen the conclusion in the last sentence to $m^*(A) > m^*(K).$ (Of course, since $K$ is measurable, we can also write this as $m^*(A) > m(K).)$

Comment: Regarding the fact that this property implies measurability of sets that have finite outer measure, see Exercises 16, 18, 19 and Remark 9 in Terence Tao's [245A, Notes 1: Lebesgue measure](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/09/09/245a-notes-1-lebesgue-measure/).